# Listeners & Memory leaks in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am practicing JavaFX.

Do I need to manage listeners manually (attach and detach them from objects) to avoid memory leaks?

The context: I have a stage with a main scene. let's call it a hub. This hub is responsible for changing scenes via changing the container of the scenes (an anchor pane). Every time the change happens I clear the container, and set the controller of the deleted scene to null.

An example :

Let's say I have a listener in the first scene. The listener listens for button clicks then I wanted to change the scene. Will the listener be active even after I have no references to the button or the scene?

```
 button.setOnMouseClicked(event->{
        System.out.println("clicked");
    });
```

Here => I load the fxml files based on a path given by clicking on a button that corresponds to a specific scene.

```
  public void load_FXML_file(String path){

        Thread load=new Thread(() -> {
            try{
                FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(path));
                AtomicReference<AnchorPane> layout=new AtomicReference<>();
                layout.set(loader.load());

                if(path.contains("Subjects")){
                    subjects_view_controller=loader.getController();
                }
                else if(path.contains("Formation")){
                    formationHubController=loader.getController();
                }
                
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    load(layout.get(),path);
                });

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        });
        load.start();

    }
```

This is where the scene change happens =>

```
public void load(AnchorPane selected_window,String path){

    if(formationHubController!=null && !path.contains("Formation")){
        formationHubController.stop_timer();
        formationHubController=null;
    }
    else if(subjects_view_controller!=null && !path.contains("Subjects")){
        subjects_view_controller.remove_data();
        subjects_view_controller=null;
    }



    FadeIn fadeIn=new FadeIn();
    if(Container.getChildren().size()!=0){
        FadeOut fadeOut=new FadeOut(Container.getChildren().get(0));
        fadeOut.play();
        fadeOut.setOnFinished(Event->{
            Container.getChildren().clear();
            Container.getChildren().add(selected_window);
            fadeIn.setNode(selected_window);
            fadeIn.play();

        });

    }
    else{

        Container.getChildren().clear();
        Container.getChildren().add(selected_window);

        fadeIn.setNode(selected_window);
        fadeIn.play();
    }

}
```

… and that's it.

And please give me a summary on what is considered a strong reference in JavaFX.

Comment: Please put more effort into your writing when posting here. This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia, less like a casual chatroom. Use proper case, punctuation, and complete sentences. Avoid chit-chat. I re-wrote your post this time, to make it intelligible.

Comment: A strong reference in JavaFX is the same thing as a strong reference in plain Java. It means code can still access the object via a reference (e.g., field). With listeners, you only have to remove them if the listener captures a reference to an object that you don't want the listener to keep alive. There's also `WeakListener` / `WeakEventHandler`, though that makes your implementation slightly more complex, and should only be a cautionary measure.

Comment: Off topic: A tool like [grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com) can help address issues that Basil brings up in his comment.  I recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your code architecture.

Your controller object reference will exist until you set it manually to null or until Javas garbage collector removes it (because it is not needed anymore). Same for the listeners.

Your best bet is to test it by yourself in your application. Just use System.outs and check if the button exists and try to click the button programatically in code.

There should be a method called `button.fire()` or `button.click()`.

Comment: what i meant is when i set the controller to null will the listeners inside the controller (button listeners , list change listeners) be gone ? will it be garbage collected ? or will the listeners keep the reference alive

Comment: If the controller is set to null, al fields won't change. Unless they are not used anymore, then they will be collected by the garbage collector.